# Why I obtain this issue related to the slideToggle() animation time in this JQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I am new in JavaScript / JQuery and I have the following problem:

In a page I have this **JQuery** script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("thead.opening").click(function () {

        var theadElement = $(this);
        var tbodyElement = $(this).next();

        var theadClass = theadElement.attr('class');

        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
            $(this).prev("thead.opening").toggleClass("active");
            $("thead.opening").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow.gif");
            $("thead.active").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow_down.gif");

            // Retrieve the class of the clicked thead element in the DOM:
            var theadClass = theadElement.attr('class');
            //alert("CLASS THEAD AFTER: " + theadClass);

            if(theadElement.hasClass('active')) {
                tbodyElement.addClass('importantRule');
            }else {
                tbodyElement.removeClass('importantRule')
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

This script is performed when the user clicks on the **thead** element of a table having **class="opening"** and works in this way:

> It calls the **slideToggle()** function on the related **tbody**
>   element of the same table (represented by **$(this).next()** because
>   the **tbody** is the next element after the **thead**).
>
> So this **tbody** is opened and closed (expanded and compressed) with
>   a specific animation speed specified by the **'slow'** parameter.

This works fine.

The problem is that I had to add the following code to fix a CSS issue related to the opened **tbody**:

```
if(theadElement.hasClass('active')) {
    tbodyElement.addClass('importantRule');
} else {
    tbodyElement.removeClass('importantRule');
}
```

This code works in this way:

> Since the **tbody** is shown (it is opened) only if its related
>   **thead** have CSS **class='active'** set.
>
> If this class is set on the **thead** then apply the CSS settings
>   described by the **importantRule** class to the **tbody** of the
>   table.
>
> Otherwise (if the **thead** does not have the **class='active'** set,
>   it means that the user is closing the tab and I have to remove this
>   settings from the **tbody** (otherwise this could not be closed).

This are the settings:

```
.expanded.importantRule {
    width: 10000000em !important;
    display: table-row-group !important;
}
```

The problem is that, performing this script (after adding the previous CSS code fix), when the user clicks on the **thead** of a table, it is opened with the specified speed of the animation but when he/she clicks on the **thead** of a table to close the related **tbody**, it is immediately closed withoud animation.

Why is the animation ignored? It seems as if this statement

```
tbodyElement.removeClass('importantRule');
```

is executed immediately and that it does not leave the animation time specified by:

```
$(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue ?

**EDIT-1:** This is the jsfiddle on a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/xyeL3m7x/2/

The problem is that it works (if you click on the thead the tbody is showed) but I dont' know why into the fiddle the animation is always immediatly load (there is no a real animation)

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) please ?

Comment: Agree. Create a minimal fiddle and link it to the question

Comment: No no no no no! We don't need JSFiddle. There's a runnable "code snippet" feature right here on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and use the code snippet feature.

Comment: @rnevius The question is already huge. Unluckily the internal SO fiddler doesn't allow to hide the code and show the result. If you put a huge amount of code in the fiddle, it will pollute the question too (with scrollbars over a certain point, ok, but as said, the question is already huge). 
I'm a fan of the SO fiddler too, but it doesn't cover *every* case.

Comment: I have inserted a jsfiddle at the end of my original post